# How to test huge methods? (Integration Testing?)

Tags: java, c#, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

I am working on a dated system. It consists out of huge methods with sometimes thousands of lines. Most methods do multiple things.
There are no comments, there are no tests.
I have realized that testing is quite good to ensure that I find errors faster (obviously..). It´s quite easy to write some Unit Tests on smaller or at least specialized methods, but I dont know how to test bigger ones.

At the moment I am testing database methods with commit/rollback, which seems to work.

I would now like to know:

->How do I rollback the database from other modules?
When I am doing it directly with the database methods it´s easy, but what if I am in the UI, with: UI (code)->logic->API->database ? How can I ensure that the database reverts back? ...or since this is only the dev database, how to let the data in the db, without having to always input new values for the tests.

->How do I test huge methods?

I have in the UI very few methods, which do a LOT of things. Doing some things in the UI, taking in user input, validating it,starting other modules, querying the database, changing UI, a with dozen different cases depending in what case we are.
How do I test those and the modules behind them? The problem is that they often are dependent on other complex objects, be it as parameter or from other modules or data in the database, which is only added to it for this one session.

Would it be a useful idea to setup UI tests instead of testing the UI Code? However, I have never done UI tests and I don´t get time for any tests at all...

..I am not allowed to Refactor anything...

Comment: In terms of a database you could use an in memory database for testing, so you don't have to concern yourself with polluting a database every time.

Comment: Why no refactoring? I'm guessing you already know this based on your question, but the best answer to your question is "don't write methods with thousands of lines that do tons of different things."

Comment: I agree with Exitaire about the in-memory database for unit testing, though - that's usually what I do. That way I can set it up just how I want it and I can just throw it away when I'm done with it without worrying about cleanup.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not seem that there is an in memory db with PL/SQL...                   @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica I am aware. However, I am not allowed to delete anything... not even code that is only in comments, "because it could be of use again"... ...Don´t ask how Version control is handled.